# Shifting cells to the left without affect its own column

Tags: excel, vba, cell

```
COLS : NO |   | B | C |   | D
  01 : 1  |   | 8 | 3 |   | 2
  02 :    |   |   | 4 |   | 
  03 :    |   |   |   |   |
  04 : 2  |   | 5 | 2 |   | 6
```

How can I shift the values to the left and delete empty rows but remain the values in it's own column? Goal is:

```
COLS : NO | B | C | D
  01 : 1  | 8 | 3 | 2
  02 :    |   | 4 | 
  03 : 2  | 5 | 2 | 6
  04 :    |   |   |
```

Number 4 in C2 should remain in it's own column (It's an extra value for record number 1 at column C).
What I get now is not what I want:

```
COLS : NO | B | C | D
  01 : 1  | 8 | 3 | 2
  02 : 4  |   |   | 
  03 : 2  | 5 | 2 | 6
  04 :    |   |   |
```

Comment: maybe you need to be thinking in terms of deleting empty columns instead of thinking in terms of shifting cells

Comment: Are you saying you want to eliminate all spaces ABOVE and to the LEFT of ALL data?

Comment: What is the NO column?

Comment: Your diagrams are confusing. Please post two images of an actual Excel range. One of the before data. One, what it looks like after the transformation.

Comment: The NO column means No. (NUMBER)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
Sub test2()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim n As Long, c As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer
    Dim vC(), vRow()

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngDB = Ws.UsedRange
    vDB = rngDB
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)

    For i = 1 To r
        Set rng = rngDB.Rows(i)
        If Not WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
            n = n + 1
            ReDim Preserve vRow(1 To n)
            vRow(n) = i
        End If
    Next i
    For i = 1 To c
        Set rng = rngDB.Columns(i)
        If Not WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) = 0 Then
            k = k + 1
            ReDim Preserve vC(1 To k)
            vC(k) = i
        End If
    Next i
    ReDim Preserve vR(1 To n, 1 To k)
    For i = 1 To n
        For j = 1 To k
            vR(i, j) = vDB(vRow(i), vC(j))
        Next j
    Next i

    Sheets.Add
    Range("a1").Resize(n, k) = vR
End Sub



Sub test()
    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim rngDB As Range, rng As Range
    Dim vDB As Variant, vR() As Variant
    Dim i As Long, r As Long
    Dim n As Long, c As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim k As Integer

    Set Ws = ActiveSheet
    Set rngDB = Ws.UsedRange
    vDB = rngDB
    r = UBound(vDB, 1)
    c = UBound(vDB, 2)
    ReDim vR(1 To r, 1 To c)
    For i = 1 To r
        Set rng = rngDB.Rows(i)
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rng) Then
            n = n + 1
            k = 0
            For j = 1 To c
                If vDB(i, j) <> "" Then
                    k = k + 1
                    vR(n, k) = vDB(i, j)
                End If
            Next j
        End If
    Next i
    'rngDB = vR  '<~~~  Use this to write on the same sheet.
    Sheets.Add
    Range("a1").Resize(r, c) = vR
End Sub
```

### Before

[image]

### After

[image]

Comment: Don't bother with Integer variable types. There is literally no point with modern hardware. There is no advantage and they can be slower than Longs.

Comment: I want to make number 4 remain at Column C

Comment: @YiHam,  The first question wasn't.

Comment: Hi, now I would like to auto delete empty cells for a report. I got your result but this is not I want. In this example, number 4 is a value of header "C" and it's belongs to the 1st record. Therefore, I should still remain number 4 and column "C" while remove the empty cells...

Comment: @YiHarn, i edited my answer.

Comment: and how if I just want to edit selected range with Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)?

Comment: Set rngDB = Ws.UsedRange  ~~>  Set rngDB = selection

Comment: Set rngDB = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

Answer (score 0):

I hope to get this result:

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cdzgj.png)

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uM0Wh.png)